# How to convert the apex class into batch apex class?

Tags: apex, soql, batch, code

```
public class MonPipelineReport{    
    public static void Get_Officer()
    {
        Date startDate = Date.today().addMonths(-1);
        startDate = Date.newInstance(startDate.year(),startDate.month(),1);
        Date endDate = startDate;
        Integer days = Date.daysInMonth(endDate.year(), endDate.month());
        endDate = Date.newInstance(startDate.year(),startDate.month(),days);
        List<Lead> allLeads = [SELECT Loan_Officer_1a__c,Loan_Officer_1a__r.Email, Name, Phone, Starting_Credit_Score__c, 
                               Status, Enrolled_On__c, Est_Re_Pull_Date__c, Realtor_Name__c 
                               FROM Lead WHERE CreatedDate >=: startDate AND CreatedDate <=: endDate AND Loan_Officer_1a__c != null LIMIT 50000];
        EmailTemplate templateId = [Select Id,HtmlValue,Subject from EmailTemplate where name = 'LoanOfficerRecord' LIMIT 1];
        Map<Id,List<Lead>> leadMap = new Map<Id,List<Lead>>();
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMEssage>();
        if(allLeads != null && allLeads.size() > 0){
            for(Lead l: allLeads){
                if(!leadMap.containsKey(l.Loan_Officer_1a__c)){
                    leadMap.put(l.Loan_Officer_1a__c, new List<lead>());
                }
                leadMap.get(l.Loan_Officer_1a__c).add(l);
            }
        }
        if(leadMap.keySet().size() > 0){
            Map<Id,Contact> officers = new Map<Id,Contact>([SELECT Id,Email,Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN: leadMap.keySet()]);
            for(Id i: leadMap.keySet()){
                Contact con = officers.get(i);
                System.debug(con);
                if(String.isnOtBlank(con.Email)){
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    mail.setToAddresses(new String[]{con.EMail});
                    mail.setSubject(templateId.Subject);
                    String html = templateId.HtmlValue;
                    html = html.replace('||OfficerName||',con.Name);
                    String leadsTable = '<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" width="100%" align="center" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">'+
                        '<tr style="font-weight:bold;"><td>Name</td><td>Phone</td><td>Starting Credit Score</td><td>Status</td><td>Enrolled On</td><td>Est. Re Pull Date</td><td>Realtor Name</td></tr>';
                    for(Lead l: leadMap.get(i)){
                        leadsTable += '<tr><td>'+l.Name+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+l.Phone+'</td><td>'+l.Starting_Credit_Score__c+'</td><td>'+l.Status+'</td><td>'+l.Enrolled_On__c+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+l.Est_Re_Pull_Date__c+'</td><td>'+l.Realtor_Name__c+'</td></tr>';
                    }
                    leadsTable += '</table>';
                    html = html.replace('||Leads||',leadsTable);
                    mail.setHTMLBody(html);
                    mails.add(mail);
                }
            }
        }
        if(mails.size() > 0){
            Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the code below.

```
global class MonPipelineReportBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public String query = 'SELECT Loan_Officer_1a__c,Loan_Officer_1a__r.Email, Name, Phone, Starting_Credit_Score__c, ' 
                          +  'Status, Enrolled_On__c, Est_Re_Pull_Date__c, Realtor_Name__c ' 
                          +   ' FROM Lead';
    public EmailTemplate templateId = [Select Id,HtmlValue,Subject from EmailTemplate where name = 'LoanOfficerRecord' LIMIT 1];

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        Date startDate = Date.today().addMonths(-1);
    startDate = Date.newInstance(startDate.year(),startDate.month(),1);
    Datetime realStartDate = Datetime.newInstance(startDate, Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0));

    Date endDate = startDate;
    Integer days = Date.daysInMonth(endDate.year(), endDate.month());
    endDate = Date.newInstance(startDate.year(),startDate.month(),days);
    Datetime realEndDate = Datetime.newInstance(endDate.addDays(1), Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0));

    query += ' WHERE CreatedDate >= ' + realStartDate + ' AND CreatedDate <= ' + realEndDate + ' AND Loan_Officer_1a__c != null';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, list<Lead> allLeads) {
        Map<Id,List<Lead>> leadMap = new Map<Id,List<Lead>>();
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMEssage>();
        if(allLeads != null && allLeads.size() > 0){
            for(Lead l: allLeads){
                if(!leadMap.containsKey(l.Loan_Officer_1a__c)){
                    leadMap.put(l.Loan_Officer_1a__c, new List<lead>());
                }
                leadMap.get(l.Loan_Officer_1a__c).add(l);
            }
        }
        if(leadMap.keySet().size() > 0){
            Map<Id,Contact> officers = new Map<Id,Contact>([SELECT Id,Email,Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN: leadMap.keySet()]);
            for(Id i: leadMap.keySet()){
                Contact con = officers.get(i);
                System.debug(con);
                if(String.isnOtBlank(con.Email)){
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    mail.setToAddresses(new String[]{con.EMail});
                    mail.setSubject(templateId.Subject);
                    String html = templateId.HtmlValue;
                    html = html.replace('||OfficerName||',con.Name);
                    String leadsTable = '<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" width="100%" align="center" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">'+
                        '<tr style="font-weight:bold;"><td>Name</td><td>Phone</td><td>Starting Credit Score</td><td>Status</td><td>Enrolled On</td><td>Est. Re Pull Date</td><td>Realtor Name</td></tr>';
                    for(Lead l: leadMap.get(i)){
                        leadsTable += '<tr><td>'+l.Name+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+l.Phone+'</td><td>'+l.Starting_Credit_Score__c+'</td><td>'+l.Status+'</td><td>'+l.Enrolled_On__c+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+l.Est_Re_Pull_Date__c+'</td><td>'+l.Realtor_Name__c+'</td></tr>';
                    }
                    leadsTable += '</table>';
                    html = html.replace('||Leads||',leadsTable);
                    mail.setHTMLBody(html);
                    mails.add(mail);
                }
            }
        }
        if(mails.size() > 0){
            Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }
   }
```

Comment: it works thank you so much ...........

Comment: please share the test class also?

Comment: Hi, the test class for batch class is the same as normal apex class. create some necessary fake data for this batch class, then use Database.executeBatch(new MonPipelineReportBatch(),200); in your test class.

Comment: 12:58:02:000 LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS   Number of query rows: 1 out of 50000 ..data is not fetched in batch class no rows affected?

Comment: Try to use the updated code again and set the batch size to 200, thx.

Comment: Would it not be better to have execute build the mails and then have them sent in one operation during the finish method? This would require the batchable to be stateful, and you will have to be careful to hold these details in a serializable object of course. You must also consider email limits: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#email_limits_section . A final point: use of an email template and mailmerge will cause an extra query per contextual object so again consider (query) limits.

Comment: still 0 rows affected ..

Comment: Note that your test should use the Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() API calls around the Database.executeBatch call used to trigger the test, otherwise the batch will not be executed.

Comment: @MuhammadJawwad Try to execute the SOQL query in 'Anonymous window' to find what is going wrong. This batch should work if the 'where statements' are right.

Comment: @MuhammadJawwad I have found the root cause of 0 rows affected. Since the 'CreatedDate' are actually datetime format, so you should change the startdate to datetime format and I have updated the code.

Comment: 15:31:10:062 FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: line 1:203 no viable alternative at character ' ' found an error

Comment: We tend to discourage "code dump" answers - a large code paste without explanation - for pretty much this reason: they lead to a lot of back and forth in the comments and don't provide as much value to other community members. SFSE's [question and answer guidelines](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help) discourage asking for code to be written.